# Using webservices in android

Tags: android, rest, soap

I have the following site  http://www.freewebservicesx.com/GoldSpotPrice.aspx which provides a webservice api. As i am extremely new to soap and rest i have absolutely no clue about how to call this service and use it in android. Could someone please tell me how to do it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the following url to refer:::

[Using ksoap2 for android, and parsing output data...](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/using-ksoap2-android-and-parsing-output-data)

[ksoap2-android - HowToUse.wiki.....](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/wiki/HowToUse)

[ksoap2-android](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)

Use this [LINK](http://android-devblog.blogspot.in/2010/06/soap-on-android.html) it has a sample the suits your requirement.

also [LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051762/android-webservice-access-error)

Comment: http://www.freewebservicesx.com/GetGoldPrice.asmx?op=GetCurrentGoldPrice is the file. How would i go about calling this from android

Answer (score 1):

You can make HTTP requests using either `HttpURLConnection` or HttpClient. Example of using `HttpClient` for a RESTful web service:

```
HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet("http://www.mywebsite.com/webservice");
HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
StatusLine statusLine = response.getStatusLine();
if (statusLine.getStatusCode() == HttpStatus.SC_OK) {
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    entity.writeTo(out);
    out.close();
    String responseStr = out.toString();
    // process response
} else {
    // handle bad response
}
```

Otherwise, if you're working with a SOAP web service, I would recommend using [ksoap2](http://code.google.com/p/ksoap2-android/)

Comment: http://www.freewebservicesx.com/GetGoldPrice.asmx?op=GetCurrentGoldPrice is the file. How would i go about calling this with username and password