# Android accessing soap service

Tags: android, soap

I am using the following code to access the webservice

```
public SoapObject getWeather() throws Exception
{
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject("http://www.freewebservicesx.com", "GetCurrentGoldPrice");
    //request.addProperty("PlaceName", city);
    request.addProperty("Username","myusername");
    request.addProperty("Password","pass");
    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);
    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
    // It seems that it is a .NET Web service because it doesn't work without next line
    envelope.dotNet = true;

    HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE("http://www.freewebservicesx.com/GetGoldPrice.asmx");
    transport.call("http://freewebservicesx.com/GetCurrentGoldPrice", envelope);

    return (SoapObject) envelope.getResponse();
}


public List<CharSequence> getWeatherForecast() 
{
    SoapObject obj = null;
    try {
        obj = getWeather();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
//error is being thrown here
        Log.e("error",e.getMessage());
    }
    SoapObject details = (SoapObject) obj.getProperty("GetCurrentGoldPriceResult");

    List<CharSequence> list = new ArrayList<CharSequence>(details.getPropertyCount());
    for (int i = 0; i < details.getPropertyCount(); i++) {
        Object property = details.getProperty(i);
        if (property instanceof SoapObject) {
            SoapObject weather = (SoapObject) property;
            String day = weather.getProperty("string").toString();
            String min = weather.getProperty("string").toString();
            //String max = weather.getProperty("MaxTemperatureF").toString();
            Log.v("ts is whait ai am ",day);

            list.add(day + " :: " + min);
        }
    }
    return list;
}
```

http://www.freewebservicesx.com/GetGoldPrice.asmx?op=GetCurrentGoldPrice contains the details of the service. I get a failed binder transaction eror.

> 04-07 11:10:01.405: W/System.err(651): SoapFault - faultcode: 'soap:Server' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. ---> System.ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10051538/using-webservices-in-android   Dont ask same questions twice just update the previous one please

Comment: Okay. But what is the issue. Why is it not returing the price

Answer (score 1):

Please change the line:

```
envelope.dotNet = "true";
```

to

```
envelope.dotNet = "false";
```

because "true" is always send a null value to webserver,so set a false..

and other thing.. in your code

```
request.addProperty("Username","myusername");

request.addProperty("Password","pass");
```

Check your parameter name (Username,Password) on both client and server  side webservice that must be same, it means it's case sensitive.

I hope code help you.

Comment: It still doesnt work. Can you check my parameters and tell me if it is right.The link is in my question.

Comment: <UserName>string</UserName> in your link  "UserName" N is capital,u eneter "Username"..,i thing this error..

Comment: I have tried that. It still doesnt work-soap:Server' faultstring: 'System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: Server was unable to process request. --->( i think theres something wrong in the way i am callin it

Comment: ok,plz try to replace SoapObject first parameter.  "http://www.freewebservicesx.com/"    add / end of the parameter..

Comment: ok,now plz to debug that code and tell me that in getWeather() method which line error come..

Comment: HttpTransportSE transport = new HttpTransportSE("http://www.freewebservicesx.com/GetGoldPrice.asmx"); // transport.call("http://freewebservicesx.com/GetCurrentGoldPrice", envelope); try { Log.e("thjsgbfkj",transport.toString()); transport.call("http://freewebservicesx.com/GetCurrentGoldPrice", envelope); } =erro. It is being printed. So something before it must be wrong.